# Hide rows of datatable based on condition in JSF2

Tags: java, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I'm using MyFaces <h:datatable> in JSF2 and I would like to hide rows based on condition like below.

But it seems that my condition doesn't work.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myController.persons}" var="person"
    styleClass="table table-striped table-lg borderless"
    headerClass="table-header borderless header-cell"
    rowClasses="table-show-row,table-hide-row"
    rowStyleClass="#{person.gender ne 'M'}">
    <h:column>
        <div>
            <div class="">
                <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                #{persone.name}
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I also tried to use only rowStyleClass but it doesn't work also

```
rowStyleClass="#{person.gender ne 'M' ? 'table-show-row': 'table-hide-row'}">
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you check that the rule defined at rowStyleClass is not overriden by another css rule ?

Comment: which another css rule do you mean ?

Comment: Look via the web browser console if your css rule 'table-show-row'/'table-hide-row' is not overriden by another rule (for e.g coming from a rule in a external css or under <style> tag

Comment: it's not overriden, I see my defined css classes, every even row gets css class 'table-hide-row' and every odd row gets css class 'table-show-row'

Comment: So your css rules have correctly been applied on components ?

Comment: not really, the condition '#{person.gender ne 'M'}' being ignored (dont know why) without it it does the same thing for every even and odd row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244947/discussion-between-codescale-and-ldropl).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple. There's no `rowStyleClass` in `h:dataTable`.

There is only a `rowClasses` attribute ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/dataTable.html)).

You can find `rowStyleClass` in [data tables from PrimeFaces](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/datatable).

Comment: I tried only RowClasses but still it doesn't work. ```rowClasses="#{person.gender ne 'M'}">``` in this case all rows are getting true class which should not be because some values should return false

Comment: This is because the attribute is `rowClasses` not `rowClass`. And in `rowClasses` you can't use `var`. So in your example `person` is `null` (at least in Mojarra).

Answer (score 0):

it was a bit tricky because in rowClasses you can't write a condition so the solution is to create in Bean a function which returns list of comma separated css classes and call it in xhtml

In Bean:

```java
    String rowStyles;

    public String getRowStyles() {
        rowStyles = "";
        for (Person person: persons) {
            rowStyles += person.getGender().equals('M') ? "table-hide-row," : "table-show-row,";
        }

        return rowStyles;
    }
```

XHTML:

```html
<h:dataTable rowClasses="#{personBean.rowStyles}" ...>
```